# I have a method that returns string however the variable is of type nullable boolean

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I get a build error in the following:

```
protected override string SHow()
{
    return _type ? "Y" : "N";
}
```

`_type` is of type nullable bool. I get that "cannot convert from ?bool to bool.

Could you please help resolve?

Comment: It doesn't know which value should be returned when _type is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nullable type provides access to its underlying value with the Value property.

`return _type.HasValue && _type.Value ? "Y" : "N";`

OK, editing to return null...

```
const string trueValue = "True";
const string falseValue = "False";

return _type.HasValue ? (_type.Value ? trueValue : falseValue) : null;
```

Comment: I did something like this below, will it work? No compile error.   return (_type==null) ?  null : Convert.ToString(_type); However, any side effects?

Comment: That also works. .HasValue is equivalent to comparing to null. However, Convert.ToString() is not desirable here, because it will return "true" or "false", and you have no way to control that. Also, in your example, you've already made sure _type is not null, so it would be better to pass in _type.Value instead, to avoid a redundant check in Convert.ToString().

Comment: I basically want to send null when no value and if there is a value of true then send yes and if a value of false then send no. So is the above code line of mine is correct? Please help

Comment: Ah, I see. Personally I would still prefer to return explicit values, rather than relying on Convert.ToString() to always behave the same way.

Comment: thank you, so in that case, can you correct my code? to send null. I meana you can update in your ans

Comment: Thank you, so instead of constant lines, I can directly use "Y" or "N" right?

Comment: Building complex conditional operation syntax is not advised for the sake of readability. Conditional operator is better used to resolve single condition, nesting multiple conditional operations should be avoided. Besides, HasValue is not required for comparison

Comment: Building complex conditional operation syntax is not advised for the sake of readability. Conditional operator is better used to resolve single condition, nesting multiple conditional operations should be avoided. Besides, HasValue is not required for comparison. _type==true? Or _type==false? works just fine. See the answer:[NullableComparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673918/best-way-to-check-for-nullable-bool-in-a-condition-expression-if)

Comment: Thanks guys and thanks Glenebob, accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
protected override string SHow() 
{
    if(_type ==null)
    {
        return "";
    }
     return _type.Value ? "Y" : "N";
 }
```

Comment: It will throw an exception when _type is null.

Comment: Check if _type is null then return something you like

Answer (score 0):

If bool? has value then It is indeed true or false. Besides nullable.HasValue is required when we want to access value not when we compare value. So the following will also work:

```
protected override string SHow()
{ 
    string result = null;
    if(_type==true)
        result = "Y"; // has value & value is true
    else if (_type==false)
        result="N"; // has value & value is false
    return result; // retuing null if no value
}
```

Statement "_type==true" will never fail or give you a compile error because compiler not only check for null, it also check for true or false and return true only if _type is NOT Null and also has value true. 
Equality comparison for any primitive type nullable behaves the same way so nullable.HasValue check is not necessary when you compare.