# Safe Navigation Operator with Any()

Tags: c#

Hey Everyone I thought that this code would be valid in any case because it is casted to bool

```
parameter.Request?.InnerData?.Any() == false
```

Instead this code is casted to type `bool?`

Can tell me someone why? (this is main question)
Is there better way to check this instead of something like this?

```
var isThereInnerData = parameter.Request?.InnerData?.Any();
if (isThereSegments == null || isThereSegments == false)
```

Comment: Because once `Request` is `null` or `Request.InnerData` is `null`, the entire expression will evaluate to `null`. Since it can return either `null` or `bool` obviously the compiler infers it as `Nullable<bool>` (`bool?`).

Comment: Insteadof `if (isThereSegments == null || isThereSegments == false)` you could just do `if (isThereSegments == true)` unless you need to write code for both scenarios as seen here ► [Best way to check for nullable bool in a condition expression (if ...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673918/best-way-to-check-for-nullable-bool-in-a-condition-expression-if)

Comment: I would imagine it makes sense for the compiler to return you a `bool?` since it is inherently uncertain if a Safe Navigation Operator will even be able to return a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what [C# reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) says about `?.` operator:

> x?.y – null conditional member access. **Returns null** if the left hand
>   operand is null.

Since at compile time the compiler doesn't knows whether the expression will evaluate to a non-null value, the compiler infers the type as `Nullable<bool>`

Since you are chaining the `?.` operator this line from msdn documentation is relevant too:

> The null-condition operators are
>   short-circuiting. If one operation in a chain of conditional member
>   access and index operation returns null, then the rest of the chain’s
>   execution stops. Other operations with lower precedence in the
>   expression continue. For example, E in the following always executes,
>   and the ?? and == operations execute.

Answer (score 2):

With a null-conditional operator, null propagates. You can't end up with a non-nullable type if you use the null-conditional operator - this is the same behaviour in languages where null operations are "safe" by default (SQL, Objective-C, ...). So the result is `default(bool?)` if `parameter.Request` is null, or `parameter.Request.InnerData` is null. Otherwise, you get true or false, but by using the null-conditional operator you already assume the result *can* in fact be null, so the compiler must accomodate that. Since `bool` can't be null, it is changed into a nullable bool (`bool?`).

The solution is simple - think about what logical value a null should have, and use that:

```
if (parameter.Request?.InnerData?.Any() ?? true)
```

In this case, a null value is interpreted as true, but you can also use false if you want. Alternatively, instead of the null-coalescing operator, you can use `GetValueOrDefault`, whatever feels better for you.

Answer (score 0):

`bool` is a value type and per default cannot be compared with `null`. C# converts your return value to `bool?` to give you the option to support both.

Comment: The question was why does the statement evaluate to a nullable bool, which has been answered in other posts.