# Object property suddenly becomes null when queried with a linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq query:

```
private List<Port> DoCountriesSearch(string search)
{
    return Countries.Where(x => x.CountrySearch.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToList();
}
```

I have an object called `Countries` which is a list of Port objects with various properties. Each Port object contains a property called `CountrySearch` which you can see here:

[image]

But as soon as I try to run the linq query on `Countries`, suddenly the `CountrySearch` property is null which throws a null reference exception:

[image]

I've never had this issue with linq before. What am I missing?

Comment: Please [edit] your post with a [mre].

Comment: The screenshots show different instances. "Germany" instance having non-nullable `CountrySearch` does not prove that "New Caledonia" will have it too.

Comment: Is `Countries` an in-memory list or a DbSet? If it's a list you can use the case-invariant version of Contains, eg `Where(x => x.CountrySearch.Contains(search,StringComparions.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`. Each call to `ToLower()` creates a new temporary string instance that has to be garbage-collected

Comment: @GuruStron the screenshots were just meant to illustrate the problem. this field will never be null no matter the instance.

Comment: This query does not make anything `null`. The `null` entries must have been there in the `Countries` list already. It would help to see how you are filling this list.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I load a DataTable object from a database query (at this point the CountrySearch value exists since it is returned as part of the query). I then have a method that iterates over the DataTable rows and reads the values in to their corresponding fields in the Port object eventually returning a list of Port objects.

Comment: The problem is probably in the *"method that iterates over the DataTable rows and reads the values in to their corresponding fields in the Port object"*. Please show us this method!

Comment: I figured out the issue! i posted an answer explaining what happened. Thanks for helping me arrive at the solution @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Answer (score 0):

Your list has a lot of entries. In some entries `CountrySearch` is not `null`, in others it is `null`. There is no magic happening with LINQ here.

You can fix this with a [Null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

```cs
private List<Port> DoCountriesSearch(string search)
{
    return Countries.Where(
        x => x.CountrySearch?.Contains(
            search,
            StringComparions.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == true
    ).ToList();
}
```

Note that `== true` is required here because we have to cope with `null` values.

See also:

- [Best way to check for nullable bool in a condition expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2673918/880990).
- [StringComparison Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison) for possible values.

Comment: This field will never be null. Each entry will always have a value since it comes straight from the database query for a non-nullable field.

Comment: *"This field will never be null."*, well it is null obviously for "New Caledonia". This `null` value was there before executing this query, because this query isn't changing any fields or properties of existing objects. How is the `Countries` list created or filled? This is most probably the place where the things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was entirely my fault. I had a buried method that was appending Port objects to the bottom of the list that did not come from the database, therefore the CountrySearch fields for those items were indeed null.