# Using null conditional operator("?.") with "function that returns a bool value"

Tags: c#, null, nullable, null-conditional-operator

```
using System;

public class A{
    public bool func(){
        return true;
    }
    

    public int func2(){
        return 10;
    }
}

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        if(a?.func()){
            Console.WriteLine("true"); // Error
        }
        
        if(a?.func2() == 10){
            Console.WriteLine("true"); // print: True
        }
    }
}
```

Like above case, I want to use null conditional operator with A function that returns a bool value.
But, It throws error only when used with bool returning function.

Can I know why it works like that?

Ironically, It works well with the phrase

```
if(a?.func() == true){
    Console.WriteLine("true"); // print: true
}
```

Comment: `a?.func()` simply does **not** return `bool`, but `bool?`.

Comment: Side note: if you'd really worked out the [mre] - `bool? r = true; if (r) ...` than you'd only need to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673918/best-way-to-check-for-nullable-bool-in-a-condition-expression-if....

Comment: `a?.func()` returns a `bool?`, the `if` condition requires a `bool`. The comparison operator `==` returns a `bool`, which is why it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, note that even if `func` returns `bool`

```
 a?.func()
```

returns *nullable* `bool?` (`true`, `false` and  ... `null`):

```
 a        : a?.func()
 ------------------------------------------
 null     : null      
 not null : a.func() # either true or false
```

So you can put

```
 // if `a` is `null` then `a?.func() is null` 
 // since `null != true` the condition true if and only if
 // `a` is not null and `a.func()` returns true
 if (a?.func() == true)
```

here .net compares `T?` and `T` instances (`T` is `bool` in our case). It does it as follow

```
 // First compute the expression
 bool? result = a?.func()

 // Then .net checks if Value is not null
 // and if it is the Value equals to required value 
 if (result.HasValue && result.Value == true) ...
```

Another way is to use `??` to map `null` into `true` or `false`

```
 // in case of null - when `a` is null - assume false
 if (a?.func() ?? false)
```

The very same logic with

```
 if (a?.func2() == 10)
```

here `a?.func2()` returns *nullable* `int?` which you compare as `== 10`, i.e.

> if `a` is *not* `null` and `a.func2()` returns `10` then...

Comment: Good answer. But lacks an explanation why you can't use `bool?` in an `if` directly but as comparison(== true or == 10). [Lifted operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370110/what-are-lifted-operators)

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement requires a boolean expression. That is, whatever is inside your parenthesis must resolve to either `true` or `false`. When you use the null-conditional operator it says, "give me the bool result of `func()` unless `a` is null, then give me null". So by adding the `?.` you change your expression to a `bool?`. But as we established, the `if` statement requires a bool. `if (null)` is invalid which is what you get when `a` is null.

So why does `if (a?.func() == true)` work? By adding `== true`, you are now changing your expression back to a `bool` result type by doing a comparison. When `a` is null, instead of being

`if (null)`

you now have

`if (null == true)`

which is a valid boolean expression that resolves to false. So incidentally, the inverse is also valid `if (a?.func() == false)`.